# how to increment string like AA

Tags: excel, vba

I have in excel, strings like that AA or XA.

I need to increment them like that

For AA in cell A1, it will be AB in cell B1, AC in cell B2 and so on

For XA in cell A1, it will be XB in cell B1, XC in cell B2 and so on.

I tried the popular `CHAR(CODE(A1)+1)` but it does not work after Z.

Any hints are welcome.

PS: I'm trying to not use VBA but if it is needed, well go for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **A1** enter:

```
=SUBSTITUTE((LEFT(ADDRESS(1,COLUMN()),3)),"$","")
```

and copy across as far as you need

**EDIT#2:**

Put an arbitrary starting value in **A1** and then in **B1** enter:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,COLUMN(INDIRECT(A1 & 1))+1,4),1,"")
```

and copy across

[image]

**EDIT#3:**

To propagate a string like:

JAMES

would require ***VBA***

Comment: Hi @Gary's student, is there not a way to do that like I put AA in cell A1 and then put the formula in B1 that will call the cell A1 and change it to AB?

Comment: I believe that `+COLUMN()-1` should be simply `+1` or the reference to `A1` should be locked as `$A$1`.

Comment: This answer is quite cool http://superuser.com/questions/867965/how-to-increment-string-like-aa